# JavaScript undefined to equal to

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

trying to create a function that results to this

```
describe('introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language)', function() {
  it('takes in two arguments, a name and a language, and language defaults to JavaScript', function() {
    expect(introductionWithLanguageOptional("Susie")).toEqual("Hi, my name is Susie and I am learning to program in JavaScript.");
  })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a function that meets that test? What was the result? You should include that code in your question.

Comment: TDD doesn't work on Stack Overflow. :P The site is for answering questions rather than writing code from scratch. How far did you get? What specifically is holding up your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

```
function introductionWithLanguageOptional(name, language = "JavaScript") {
 return `Hi, my name is ${name} and I am learning to program in ${language}.`
}
```